# WINAPI remote update of cached domain credentials using logon

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory

I want to remotely update cached logon credentials for windows. I checked Ntsecapi.h to see if I could create a logon session remotely which could trigger this however I lack some good ideas. Anyone?